# Python JSON Parsing Weirdness

Tags: python, json

Using Requests I'm able to get and print a chunk of JSON:

snippet:

```
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
print json_data
```

Result:

```
{u'Events': {u'event': [{u'numMarkets': 1, u'offeredInplay': False, u'compName': u'Killarney 16 May', u'eventInfo': {u'meetingDate': 1463356800000L, u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'courseId': 212, u'raceTitle': u'KILLARNEY RACEGOERS CLUB (LADIES PRO/AM) I.N.H. FLAT', u'eligibilityAgeMin': 5, u'ipHintsOverallPace': u'', u'courseName': u'KILLARNEY', u'startTimeGMTScheduled': 1463428200000L, u'going': u'Good', u'raceClass': u'', u'finishingTime': 0.0, u'ipHintsSpecificPace': u'', u'numberOfRunners': 11, u'raceSurfaceChar': u'T', u'raceSurfaceName': u'Turf', u'entries': [], u'drawComment': u'', u'eligibilityAgeMax': u'7', u'raceTypeChar': u'N', u'actualTimeGMTScheduled': 1463356800000L, u'distanceText': u'2M 1F', u'analystVerdict': u"Those with experience don't set the bar that high and point winner PRODUCT OF LOVE might be up to making a successful start to his career under Rules. The Gordon Elliott-trained Everyday Everyhour and recent Ballinrobe third Slippery Serpent head the dangers. "}, u'name': u'20:50 Killarney', u'compId': 4123303, u'missingKeyMarket': True, u'eventTime': 1463428200000L, u'displayed': True, u'state': u'ACTIVE', u'categoryId': 4116452, u'locale': u'en-gb', u'participants': {u'participant': []}, u'pastForm': [], u'path': u'2505266:3838985:4116452:4123303:4123318', u'attributes': {u'attrib': [{u'key': u'cashoutAvailable', u'value': u'false'}, {u'key': u'TvDataChannel', u'value': u'ATR'}, {u'key': u'TvDataStartTime', u'value': u'1463415600000'}, {u'key': u'TvDataEndTime', u'value': u'1463428200000'}]}, u'compWeighting': 0.5, u'sport': u'HORSE_RACING', u'markets': [{u'columnCount': 1, u'selection': [{u'name': u'Concarlaimee Jesel', u'form': {u'rating123': 0, u'horse': {u'damName': u'GINCELL LADY (IRE)', u'performances': [], u'horseName': u'CONCARLAIMEE JESEL (IRE)', u'sireName': u'MAHLER'}, u'meetingDate': 1463356800000L, u'horseCode': u'000000437916', u'crsDisWinFavText': u'', u'saddleCloth': 10, u'draw': 0, u'jockeyName': u'Miss S. Ahern', u'weightCarried': 161, u'analystsComments': u'Mahler mare. Half-sister to winning pointer Another Aboo. Dam ran twice on Flat. Yard in good form.', u'apprenticeClaim': 7, u'trainerName': u'John J. Walsh, Ireland', u'ratingStars': 2, u'formFigures': u'', u'horseName': u'CONCARLAIMEE JESEL (IRE)', u'horseAge': 5}, u'odds': {u'rootIdx': 129, u'dec': u'46', u'frac': u'45/1'}, u'pos': {u'col': 1, u'row': 10}, u'suspended': False, u'attributes': {u'attrib': [{u'key': u'trainer', u'value': u'J J Walsh'}, {u'key': u'weight', u'value': u'11 7'}, {u'key': u'jockey', u'value': u'Miss S Ahern'}, {u'key': u'age', u'value': u'5'}, {u'key': u'image', u'value': u'20160516kil205010.png'}, {u'key': u'priceHistory', u'value': u'129,126,127'}]}, u'type': u'HORSE-2215506', u'id': 160845479}, {u'name': u'Slippery Serpent N/R', u'form': {u'rating123': 3, u'draw': 0, u'meetingDate': 1463356800000L, u'horseCode': u'000000409367', u'crsDisWinFavText': u'', u'saddleCloth': 9, u'horse': {u'damName': u'TRES CHIC (IRE)', u'performances': [{u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2016-05-03T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'BALLINROBE', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 3, u'jockeyName': u'Mr K. E. Power', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M 1F 50Y', u'going': u'Soft', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}, {u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2015-12-28T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'LIMERICK', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 3, u'jockeyName': u'Mr K. E. Power', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M', u'going': u'Heavy', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}, {u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2015-11-29T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'FAIRYHOUSE', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 7, u'jockeyName': u'Mr D. G. Lavery', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M', u'going': u'Heavy', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}], u'horseName': u'SLIPPERY SERPENT (IRE)', u'sireName': u'SCORPION (IRE)'}, u'jockeyName': u'Miss E. McCutcheon', u'daysOff': 13, u'analystsComments': u'Thrice-raced maiden. Third of 10 in bumper (5/1) at Ballinrobe (17.2f, soft) 13 days ago, going with enthusiasm.', u'apprenticeClaim': 7, u'trainerName': u"E. J. O'Grady, Ireland", u'ratingStars': 4, u'formFigures': u'73-3', u'horseName': u'SLIPPERY SERPENT (IRE)', u'horseAge': 5, u'weightCarried': 168}, u'odds': {u'rootIdx': 110, u'dec': u'9.5', u'frac': u'17/2'}, u'displayed': True, u'pos': {u'col': 1, u'row': 9}, u'suspended': True, u'attributes': {u'attrib': [{u'key': u'trainer', u'value': u"E J O'Grady"}, {u'key': u'weight', u'value': u'12 0'}, {u'key': u'jockey', u'value': u'Miss E McCutcheon'}, {u'key': u'age', u'value': u'5'}, {u'key': u'form', u'value': u'JUMP_SIX=73-3'}, {u'key': u'image', u'value': u'20160516kil205009.png'}, {u'key': u'priceHistory', u'value': u'110,109,108'}]}, u'type': u'HORSE-2180835', u'id': 160845478}, {u'name': u'Product Of Love', u'form': {u'rating123': 1, u'horse': {u'damName': u'ANNSHOON (IRE)', u'performances': [], u'horseName': u'PRODUCT OF LOVE (IRE)', u'sireName': u'FRUITS OF LOVE (USA)'}, u'meetingDate': 1463356800000L, u'horseCode': u'000000397000', u'crsDisWinFavText': u'', u'saddleCloth': 8, u'draw': 0, u'jockeyName': u"Miss A. B. O'Connor", u'weightCarried': 168, u'analystsComments': u'Off mark in points on second attempt in September. Joined yard with a good record in bumpers and this looks a winnable race. ', u'apprenticeClaim': 7, u'trainerName': u'Alan Fleming, Ireland', u'ratingStars': 5, u'formFigures': u'', u'horseName': u'PRODUCT OF LOVE (IRE)', u'horseAge': 5}, u'odds': {u'rootIdx': 59, u'dec': u'2.4', u'frac': u'7/5'}, u'pos': {u'col': 1, u'row': 8}, u'suspended': False, u'attributes': {u'attrib': [{u'key': u'trainer', u'value': u'A Fleming'}, {u'key': u'weight', u'value': u'12 0'}, {u'key': u'jockey', u'value': u"Miss A B O'Connor"}, {u'key': u'age', u'value': u'5'}, {u'key': u'form', u'value': u'JUMP_SIX=21-'}, {u'key': u'image', u'value': u'20160516kil205008.png'}, {u'key': u'priceHistory', u'value': u'59,63,61'}]}, u'type': u'HORSE-2131152', u'id': 160845477}, {u'name': u'Winsor Vixen', u'form': {u'rating123': 0, u'draw': 0, u'meetingDate': 1463356800000L, u'horseCode': u'000000409701', u'crsDisWinFavText': u'', u'saddleCloth': 12, u'horse': {u'damName': u'SAMARDANA (IRE)', u'performances': [{u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2016-04-25T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'TRAMORE', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 5, u'jockeyName': u'Mr D. Kiely', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M', u'going': u'Gd/Frm', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}, {u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2016-02-04T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'CLONMEL', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 14, u'jockeyName': u'M. P. Walsh', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M 110Y', u'going': u'Heavy', u'raceType': u'Hurdle', u'entries': []}}, {u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2015-12-06T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'PUNCHESTOWN', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 12, u'jockeyName': u'Mr A. McCurtin', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M', u'going': u'Heavy', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}], u'horseName': u'WINSOR VIXEN (IRE)', u'sireName': u'KAYF TARA'}, u'jockeyName': u"Miss M. O'Sullivan", u'daysOff': 21, u'analystsComments': u'Thrice-raced maiden under NH rules. Fifth of 15 in bumper (25/1) at Tramore (16f, good to firm) 21 days ago.', u'apprenticeClaim': 7, u'trainerName': u'John E. Kiely, Ireland', u'ratingStars': 3, u'formFigures': u'00-5', u'horseName': u'WINSOR VIXEN (IRE)', u'horseAge': 5, u'weightCarried': 161}, u'odds': {u'rootIdx': 109, u'dec': u'9', u'frac': u'8/1'}, u'pos': {u'col': 1, u'row': 12}, u'suspended': False, u'attributes': {u'attrib': [{u'key': u'trainer', u'value': u'J E Kiely'}, {u'key': u'weight', u'value': u'11 7'}, {u'key': u'jockey', u'value': u"Miss M O'Sullivan"}, {u'key': u'age', u'value': u'5'}, {u'key': u'form', u'value': u'JUMP_SIX=00-5'}, {u'key': u'image', u'value': u'20160516kil205012.png'}, {u'key': u'priceHistory', u'value': u'109,108,107'}]}, u'type': u'HORSE-2182084', u'id': 160845476}, {u'name': u'Naturally Blond', u'form': {u'rating123': 0, u'draw': 0, u'meetingDate': 1463356800000L, u'horseCode': u'000000398051', u'crsDisWinFavText': u'', u'saddleCloth': 7, u'horse': {u'damName': u'THEBIGTWELVE (IRE)', u'performances': [{u'equipmentDescription': u'tongue strap', u'meetingDate': u'2016-05-12T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'TIPPERARY', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 2, u'jockeyName': u'Mr D. Murphy', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M 2F', u'going': u'Heavy', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}, {u'equipmentDescription': u'tongue strap', u'meetingDate': u'2015-08-03T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'CORK', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 9, u'jockeyName': u'Mr D. Murphy', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M 3F', u'going': u'Good', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}, {u'equipmentDescription': u'tongue strap', u'meetingDate': u'2015-07-10T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'CORK', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 4, u'jockeyName': u'Mr D. Murphy', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M 3F', u'going': u'Good', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}], u'horseName': u'NATURALLY BLOND (IRE)', u'sireName': u'BACH (IRE)'}, u'jockeyName': u'Miss Liz Lalor', u'daysOff': 4, u'analystsComments': u'Lightly-raced maiden. Good second of 16 in bumper (33/1) at Tipperary (18f, heavy) 4 days ago, sticking to task.', u'apprenticeClaim': 5, u'trainerName': u'Patrick Cronin, Ireland', u'ratingStars': 4, u'formFigures': u'449-2', u'horseName': u'NATURALLY BLOND (IRE)', u'horseAge': 6, u'weightCarried': 168}, u'odds': {u'rootIdx': 101, u'dec': u'5.5', u'frac': u'9/2'}, u'pos': {u'col': 1, u'row': 7}, u'suspended': False, u'attributes': {u'attrib': [{u'key': u'trainer', u'value': u'Patrick Cronin'}, {u'key': u'weight', u'value': u'12 0'}, {u'key': u'jockey', u'value': u'Miss E A Lalor'}, {u'key': u'age', u'value': u'6'}, {u'key': u'form', u'value': u'JUMP_SIX=4492-2'}, {u'key': u'image', u'value': u'20160516kil205007.png'}, {u'key': u'priceHistory', u'value': u'101,99,101'}]}, u'type': u'HORSE-2134971', u'id': 160845475}, {u'name': u'Love The Well', u'form': {u'rating123': 0, u'horse': {u'damName': u'JUNGA CONNECTION', u'performances': [], u'horseName': u'LOVE THE WELL (IRE)', u'sireName': u'FRUITS OF LOVE (USA)'}, u'meetingDate': 1463356800000L, u'horseCode': u'000000437918', u'crsDisWinFavText': u'', u'saddleCloth': 6, u'draw': 0, u'jockeyName': u'Miss K. Harrington', u'weightCarried': 168, u'analystsComments': u'\u20ac4,000 4-y-o, Fruits of Love gelding. Brother to fair hurdler/chaser Pat Garrett. Dam unraced half-sister to useful hurdler (stayed 2\xbdm) Eastwell Hall.', u'apprenticeClaim': 5, u'trainerName': u'E. D. Linehan, Ireland', u'ratingStars': 2, u'formFigures': u'', u'horseName': u'LOVE THE WELL (IRE)', u'horseAge': 5}, u'odds': {u'rootIdx': 129, u'dec': u'46', u'frac': u'45/1'}, u'pos': {u'col': 1, u'row': 6}, u'suspended': False, u'attributes': {u'attrib': [{u'key': u'trainer', u'value': u'E Linehan'}, {u'key': u'weight', u'value': u'12 0'}, {u'key': u'jockey', u'value': u'Miss K Harrington'}, {u'key': u'age', u'value': u'5'}, {u'key': u'image', u'value': u'20160516kil205006.png'}, {u'key': u'priceHistory', u'value': u'129,126,127'}]}, u'type': u'HORSE-2215508', u'id': 160845474}, {u'name': u'Dark Pockets', u'form': {u'rating123': 0, u'horse': {u'damName': u'EVANNIA (IRE)', u'performances': [], u'horseName': u'DARK POCKETS (IRE)', u'sireName': u'CAPTAIN RIO'}, u'meetingDate': 1463356800000L, u'horseCode': u'000000437796', u'crsDisWinFavText': u'', u'saddleCloth': 4, u'draw': 0, u'jockeyName': u'Rachael Blackmore', u'weightCarried': 168, u'analystsComments': u'Captain Rio gelding. Dam ran twice in bumpers.', u'apprenticeClaim': 7, u'trainerName': u'Eoin Griffin, Ireland', u'ratingStars': 2, u'formFigures': u'', u'horseName': u'DARK POCKETS (IRE)', u'horseAge': 5}, u'odds': {u'rootIdx': 130, u'dec': u'51', u'frac': u'50/1'}, u'pos': {u'col': 1, u'row': 4}, u'suspended': False, u'attributes': {u'attrib': [{u'key': u'trainer', u'value': u'E Griffin'}, {u'key': u'weight', u'value': u'12 0'}, {u'key': u'jockey', u'value': u'Rachael Blackmore'}, {u'key': u'age', u'value': u'5'}, {u'key': u'image', u'value': u'20160516kil205004.png'}, {u'key': u'priceHistory', u'value': u'130,128,129'}]}, u'type': u'HORSE-2215157', u'id': 160845473}, {u'name': u'Bitview Colin', u'form': {u'rating123': 0, u'draw': 0, u'meetingDate': 1463356800000L, u'horseCode': u'000000405566', u'crsDisWinFavText': u'', u'saddleCloth': 3, u'horse': {u'damName': u'MADAME STELLA (FR)', u'performances': [{u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2015-12-22T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'CLONMEL', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 7, u'jockeyName': u'Mr T. N. Brett', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M 4F', u'going': u'Heavy', u'raceType': u'Hurdle', u'entries': []}}, {u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2015-11-04T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'FAIRYHOUSE', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 7, u'jockeyName': u'A. E. Lynch', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M', u'going': u'Gd/Sft', u'raceType': u'Hurdle', u'entries': []}}, {u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2015-10-02T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'GOWRAN PARK', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 5, u'jockeyName': u'Mr T. N. Brett', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M', u'going': u'Good', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}], u'horseName': u'BITVIEW COLIN (IRE)', u'sireName': u"WHITMORE'S CONN (USA)"}, u'jockeyName': u'Miss G. Ryan', u'daysOff': 146, u'analystsComments': u'Thrice-raced maiden under NH rules. Seventh of 10 in novice hurdle at Clonmel (20f, heavy, 66/1) 146 days ago. Switches from hurdles to bumpers.', u'apprenticeClaim': 7, u'trainerName': u'John Patrick Ryan, Ireland', u'ratingStars': 2, u'formFigures': u'577-', u'horseName': u'BITVIEW COLIN (IRE)', u'horseAge': 5, u'weightCarried': 168}, u'odds': {u'rootIdx': 140, u'dec': u'101', u'frac': u'100/1'}, u'pos': {u'col': 1, u'row': 3}, u'suspended': False, u'attributes': {u'attrib': [{u'key': u'trainer', u'value': u'J P Ryan'}, {u'key': u'weight', u'value': u'12 0'}, {u'key': u'jockey', u'value': u'Miss G Ryan'}, {u'key': u'age', u'value': u'5'}, {u'key': u'form', u'value': u'JUMP_SIX=577-'}, {u'key': u'image', u'value': u'20160516kil205003.png'}, {u'key': u'priceHistory', u'value': u'140,136,140'}]}, u'type': u'HORSE-2170426', u'id': 160845472}, {u'name': u"All The J's", u'form': {u'rating123': 0, u'draw': 0, u'meetingDate': 1463356800000L, u'horseCode': u'000000409689', u'crsDisWinFavText': u'', u'saddleCloth': 2, u'horse': {u'damName': u'CHROMAZONE', u'performances': [{u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2016-01-27T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'THURLES', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 11, u'jockeyName': u'Mr J. J. Codd', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M', u'going': u'Heavy', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}, {u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2015-12-14T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'NAVAN', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 9, u'jockeyName': u'Mr S. Clements', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M', u'going': u'Heavy', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}], u'horseName': u"ALL THE J'S (IRE)", u'sireName': u'BENEFICIAL'}, u'jockeyName': u"Katie O'Farrell", u'daysOff': 110, u'analystsComments': u'Twice-raced maiden. Eleventh of 16 in bumper at Thurles (16f, heavy, 16/1) 110 days ago.', u'apprenticeClaim': 7, u'trainerName': u'J. R. Barry, Ireland', u'ratingStars': 2, u'formFigures': u'90-', u'horseName': u"ALL THE J'S (IRE)", u'horseAge': 6, u'weightCarried': 168}, u'odds': {u'rootIdx': 123, u'dec': u'26', u'frac': u'25/1'}, u'pos': {u'col': 1, u'row': 2}, u'suspended': False, u'attributes': {u'attrib': [{u'key': u'trainer', u'value': u'J R Barry'}, {u'key': u'weight', u'value': u'12 0'}, {u'key': u'jockey', u'value': u"Katie O'Farrell"}, {u'key': u'age', u'value': u'6'}, {u'key': u'form', u'value': u'JUMP_SIX=90-'}, {u'key': u'image', u'value': u'20160516kil205002.png'}, {u'key': u'priceHistory', u'value': u'123,128,126'}]}, u'type': u'HORSE-2182076', u'id': 160845471}, {u'name': u'Al Le Gone', u'form': {u'rating123': 0, u'draw': 0, u'meetingDate': 1463356800000L, u'horseCode': u'000000433945', u'crsDisWinFavText': u'', u'saddleCloth': 1, u'horse': {u'damName': u'APPLEPOM (FR)', u'performances': [{u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2016-03-24T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'THURLES', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 7, u'jockeyName': u'Mr F. Maguire', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M', u'going': u'Soft', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}], u'horseName': u'AL LE GONE (FR)', u'sireName': u'AL NAMIX (FR)'}, u'jockeyName': u"Ms L. O'Neill", u'daysOff': 53, u'analystsComments': u'Once-raced maiden. 14/1, seventh of 13 in bumper at Thurles (16f, soft) on NH debut 53 days ago.', u'apprenticeClaim': 7, u'trainerName': u'Miss Elizabeth Doyle, Ireland', u'ratingStars': 3, u'formFigures': u'7-', u'horseName': u'AL LE GONE (FR)', u'horseAge': 5, u'weightCarried': 168}, u'odds': {u'rootIdx': 118, u'dec': u'17', u'frac': u'16/1'}, u'pos': {u'col': 1, u'row': 1}, u'suspended': False, u'attributes': {u'attrib': [{u'key': u'trainer', u'value': u'Miss E Doyle'}, {u'key': u'weight', u'value': u'12 0'}, {u'key': u'jockey', u'value': u"Ms L O'Neill"}, {u'key': u'age', u'value': u'5'}, {u'key': u'form', u'value': u'JUMP_SIX=7-'}, {u'key': u'image', u'value': u'20160516kil205001.png'}, {u'key': u'priceHistory', u'value': u'118,116,118'}]}, u'type': u'HORSE-2200898', u'id': 160845470}, {u'name': u'Vintage Salon', u'form': {u'rating123': 0, u'draw': 0, u'meetingDate': 1463356800000L, u'horseCode': u'000000432915', u'crsDisWinFavText': u'', u'saddleCloth': 11, u'horse': {u'damName': u'LOUNAOS (FR)', u'performances': [{u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2016-05-08T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'LIMERICK', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 6, u'jockeyName': u'Ms K. Walsh', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M', u'going': u'Gd/Sft', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}, {u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2016-03-14T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'CORK', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 8, u'jockeyName': u'Ms K. Walsh', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M', u'going': u'Heavy', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}], u'horseName': u'VINTAGE SALON (IRE)', u'sireName': u"KING'S THEATRE (IRE)"}, u'jockeyName': u'Ms K. Walsh', u'daysOff': 8, u'analystsComments': u'Twice-raced maiden. Sixth of 10 in bumper (25/1) at Limerick (16f, good to soft) 8 days ago.', u'apprenticeClaim': 0, u'trainerName': u'James A. Nash, Ireland', u'ratingStars': 2, u'formFigures': u'8-6', u'horseName': u'VINTAGE SALON (IRE)', u'horseAge': 5, u'weightCarried': 161}, u'odds': {u'rootIdx': 126, u'dec': u'34', u'frac': u'33/1'}, u'pos': {u'col': 1, u'row': 11}, u'suspended': False, u'attributes': {u'attrib': [{u'key': u'trainer', u'value': u'J Nash'}, {u'key': u'weight', u'value': u'11 7'}, {u'key': u'jockey', u'value': u'Ms K Walsh'}, {u'key': u'age', u'value': u'5'}, {u'key': u'form', u'value': u'JUMP_SIX=8-6'}, {u'key': u'image', u'value': u'20160516kil205011.png'}, {u'key': u'priceHistory', u'value': u'126,123,124'}]}, u'type': u'HORSE-2194956', u'id': 160845480}, {u'name': u'Everyday Everyhour', u'form': {u'rating123': 2, u'draw': 0, u'meetingDate': 1463356800000L, u'horseCode': u'000000396691', u'crsDisWinFavText': u'', u'saddleCloth': 5, u'horse': {u'damName': u'CANDELLO', u'performances': [{u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2016-02-11T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'THURLES', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 3, u'jockeyName': u'Mr L. J. McGuinness', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M', u'going': u'Heavy', u'raceType': u'Bumper', u'entries': []}}, {u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2015-12-10T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'PUNCHESTOWN', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 5, u'jockeyName': u'B. J. Cooper', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M 2F', u'going': u'Heavy', u'raceType': u'Hurdle', u'entries': []}}, {u'equipmentDescription': u'', u'meetingDate': u'2015-11-01T00:00:00', u'handicapMark': 0, u'courseName': u'NAAS', u'positionStatus': u'', u'positionOfficial': 7, u'jockeyName': u'L. P. Dempsey', u'race': {u'distanceText': u'2M', u'going': u'Good', u'raceType': u'Hurdle', u'entries': []}}], u'horseName': u'EVERYDAY EVERYHOUR', u'sireName': u'PRESENTING'}, u'jockeyName': u'Miss N. Carberry', u'daysOff': 95, u'analystsComments': u'Lightly-raced maiden under NH rules. 5/1, third of 7 in bumper at Thurles (16f, heavy) 95 days ago. Stable in good form. Should go close. ', u'apprenticeClaim': 0, u'trainerName': u'Gordon Elliott, Ireland', u'ratingStars': 4, u'formFigures': u'6753-', u'horseName': u'EVERYDAY EVERYHOUR', u'horseAge': 5, u'weightCarried': 168}, u'odds': {u'rootIdx': 101, u'dec': u'5.5', u'frac': u'9/2'}, u'pos': {u'col': 1, u'row': 5}, u'suspended': False, u'attributes': {u'attrib': [{u'key': u'trainer', u'value': u'G Elliott'}...
```

The full dump is too big for SO but is [here](http://pastebin.com/fsYMeKr0) if you're curious enough.

All well and good I thought. Data is sitting right there in the print but I've never really worked with dictionaries or this end of JSON objects before.

From what I gather the u' unicode stuff in there doesn't matter and is only displaying in the print dump.

I've tried using JSONview and found an example of a value I wanted and tried:

```
print(json_data['Events.event[2].markets[1].selection[0].attributes.attrib[0].value'])
```

But I got a KeyError.

After trying a **lot** of variations and even something as simple as:

```
print(json_data['Events.event[0]'])
```

I'm still getting KeyError.

So I'm clearly doing something wrong somewhere. I haven't the foggiest what that might be though. I'd appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction or point out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(json_data['Events.event[2].markets[1].selection[0].attributes.attrib[0].value'])
```

That's not how you index a nested data structure. Perform indexing operations one at a time. Also, Python does not have any equivalence between bracket and dot notation; dicts should always be indexed with brackets:

```
print(json_data['Events']['event'][2]['markets'][1]['selection'][0]['attributes']['attrib'][0]['value'])
```

(The access syntax is essentially identical to how you would do it in Javascript if you couldn't use dotted access.)

Comment: Every time I think I understand Python Syntax I come across something like this. That's perfect thanks wish I'd known that a few hours ago. Just need to work out how to loop through occurrences now without exception breaking out of a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be as simple as `print(json_data[Events.event[0]])` meaning you are using quotes on a variable inside the json_data object?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `keyerror` because these keys doesn't exist in the dictionary. Try to use `get` method, e.g.:

```
json_data.get("key",None)
```

If key exists, it will return the value, None otherwise.

Otherwise, if you are sure that the particular key exists, you can do something like:

```
json_data["key1"][0]["key2"]
```

Comment: I looked into the Key error but I don't understand why it wouldn't be there when JSONview can see it. And the basic test one: print(json_data['Events.event[0]']) I don't understand why that wouldn't work. That's there even in that snippet.

Comment: It shouldn't work because here the index is `Events`. Now, Inside that there is another index `event`. So, if you want to access this, you need to do something like `json_data['Events']['event']` and so on.